# I have written a trigger and class to first create an account and then 10 identical opportunities. It is working but only creating 1 opportunity

Tags: trigger, opportunity, class, account

```
trigger IdenticalopportunityAccount on Account (after insert) {
    List<opportunity> oppt = new List<opportunity>();
        for(Account acctOpp1 : Trigger.new) {
            if(acctOpp1.NumberOfEmployees>99) {
                Opportunity newOpp = new Opportunity();
                newOpp.AccountId = acctOpp1.id;
                newOpp.Name = 'First';
                newOpp.StageName = 'Prospecting';
                newOpp.CloseDate = Date.today();
                oppt.add(newOpp);
            }    
        }
        insert oppt;   
}
```

my class is

```
@IsTest
    public class TenIdenticalOpportunity {
        public static void createOpportunity() {
                Account acctOpp1 = new Account();
                acctOpp1.Name = 'First';
                insert acctOpp1;
                if(acctOpp1.NumberOfEmployees>99) {
                    for(integer i=0;i<10;i++) {
                    opportunity identical = new opportunity();
                    identical.AccountId = acctOpp1.id;
                    identical.Name     = 'Identical';
                    identical.CloseDate     =  Date.today();
                    identical.StageName    = 'Prospecting';     
                    //oppt.add(identical); 
                    insert identical;                 
                    }
                }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set the cctOpp1.NumberOfEmployees field to a value over 99 so it would never enter your loop in the test class to create multiple accounts nor would it enter your logic in the trigger to create Opportunities as you have the same condition set (> 99).

```
@IsTest
    public class TenIdenticalOpportunity {
        public static void createOpportunity() {
                Account acctOpp1 = new Account();
                acctOpp1.Name = 'First';

                //Set the value above 99 to enter your criteria in next line to create multiple.
                acctOpp1.NumberOfEmployees = 100;

                insert acctOpp1;
                if(acctOpp1.NumberOfEmployees>99) {
                    for(integer i=0;i<10;i++) {
                    opportunity identical = new opportunity();
                    identical.AccountId = acctOpp1.id;
                    identical.Name     = 'Identical';
                    identical.CloseDate     =  Date.today();
                    identical.StageName    = 'Prospecting';     
                    //oppt.add(identical); 
                    insert identical;                 
                    }
                }
       }
}
```

Comment: Hi I changed the code as suggested by you but still it is creating only 1 opportunity. My code is as below:-

Comment: it is still not creating 10 opportunities. So where do I add the code that you have suggested

Comment: You're only creating one account in your test class so your trigger would only create one opportunity. Your trigger is designed to create one opp for every account inserted. What were you trying to do in your trigger and what are you trying to do in your test class?

Comment: I want to create  a single account under which there will be 10 identical opportunities

Comment: Then you need to add a for loop to create 10 opportunities in the trigger. Right now, you're only creating one opp for each account.

Comment: Yes I have added for loop in trigger and yes now it creates 10 identical opportunities.  I want the data to come from the test class. It is not getting data from the test class plus the coverage is showing 0%.